# Issues with matrix manipulation

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have two matrices A and B and a matrix C where

C=A/B

Now I want to take the derivative of C which is

```
(B*dA/dx - A*dB/dx)/B^2
```

I am not sure how the above is gonna look like. I found somewhere that it could look like

```
(B/B)*((dA/dx)/B) - (A/B)*(dB/dx)/B
```

I am confused what sort of operations can I perform. Can I do this

```
(B/B^2) * (dA/dx) - (A/B^2)*(dB/dx)
```

I tried the above two and they gave me different results. I am not sure what operations are permitted, in the case of matrices especially multiplication and division. So can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your matrices `A` and `B` are the same size, and both square. If this is not the case then please let me know.

In that case, `A/B` is the same thing as `A * inv(B)`. To differentiate this, you use the normal Leibniz rule for differentiation, being careful to keep the products in the same order (since matrix multiplication doesn't commute):

```
d/dx (A * inv(B)) = dA/dx * inv(B) + A * d(inv(B))/dx
```

If you check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Derivative_of_the_matrix_inverse) you can find that the derivative of a matrix inverse is

```
d(inv(B))/dx = -inv(B) * dB/dx * inv(B)
```

so for the derivative of the product you get

```
d/dx (A * inv(B)) = dA/dx * inv(B) - A * inv(B) * dB/dx * inv(B)
```

You can factor out the multiplication by `inv(B)` on both sides, giving

```
d/dx (A * inv(B)) = (dA/dx - A * inv(B) * dB/dx) * inv(B)
```

and you might now like to write the expression using the Matlab left and right division operators, giving

```
d/dx (A/B) = (dA/dx - (A/B) * dB/dx) / B
```

which is the most concise you can make it. In general you don't expect any of `A`, `B`, `dA/dx` or `dB/dx` to commute with each other, so you can't simplify this any more. Of course, if in your application you *do* have some reason that some of those matrices will always commute, then further simplifications may be possible.